# CRM 2011 system job reporting - which tables or views to use

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I want to write reports in SSRS for CRM 2011 system jobs (processes). This is so I can hunt down processes that are still running or have weird postpone until dates.

Which tables or views in CRM 2011 should I be querying?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [FilteredAsyncOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328118.aspx).